# Can't locate 'hdf5.h' during test

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I tried to install the HDF5 library. I followed this guide [Install_HDF5](http://micro.stanford.edu/wiki/Install_HDF5). In particular, I used:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-mpich-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-openmpi-dev
```

Up to this moment all the installations were successful. I tried to test it (`make test`) still following the guide, but I get:

```
fatal error hdf5.h no such file or directory
```

Could it concern a problem with my `~/.bashrc`, i.e. with some missing path to hdf5?

P.S. I tested the Python module of HDF5 and it is working. I only received a warning message that I got rid of by using:

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install git+https:://github.com/h5py/h5py.git --upgrade
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot provide you with an answer. But: (1) What OS are you use? (2) Can you try to `find / -iname 'hdf5.h' 2>/dev/null`. (3) I don't get your remarks of pip? Why didn't you use `pip install h5py`? What errors did you get? Why was that a problem?

Comment: @TomdeGeus thanks a lot for your help. I have Ubuntu 16.04. The result of point (2) is two files located in `anaconda2/.../hdf5.h` . I installed h5py but my problem is to use hdf5 library with C or C++ not from inside python only.

Comment: Alright. Then it's a matter of setting the correct paths at the right places. But honestly I would just install `hdf5` twice, once for `h5py` in Anaconda, and once with the normal package manager (`apt`). It will only take a few mb I think. Also I think that the format should be robust to slightly different versions (if that is what worries you).